# If statement in NSUserDefault when loading a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, loading, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code for saving a value and an string. I want to use If statement to check my value.

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:@"Baseball bat" forKey:@"Weaponsname"];
    NSInteger Attack1 = [defaults integerForKey:@"Attack"];

     NSString *Weapon = [defaults stringForKey:@"Weaponsname"];
    if([Weapon  isEqual: @"Baseball bat"]){
        [defaults setInteger:(Attack1+50) forKey:@"Attack"];
        NSLog(@"Baseball bat");
    }


        [defaults synchronize];
```

So if i have the Baseball bat, the Attack should increase by 50. But it doesn't. 
What wrong with the code?
Thanks

Comment: Could you try with isEqualToString: ? Oh wait, you should sync after setting "Baseball bat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string comparison you should use the isEqualToString method found in the NSString class.

```
if ([Weapon isEqualToString:@"Baseball bat"]) { ... }
```